# Computed GOTO fails to execute

Tags: fortran, goto, fortran77, go-to-definition

I encounter a strange behaviour in Fortran 77 code (gfortran compiler),
the following line works perfectly (jumping to label 202 for iprob=202):

```
      if( iprob .eq. 202 ) goto 202
      !...some commands...
  202 continue
```

However, its counterpart:

```
      GO TO ( 202 ), iprob
      !...some commands...
  202 continue
```

doesn't. The program just runs through for iprob=202.

Maybe anybody has an idea on that issue?

Comment: Are you saying that, in the computed goto case, `iprob` has value `202`, not `1`?

Comment: Yes, iprob=202 in both cases. I am aware of the documentation and can't find anything wrong in the computed go-to case. Thus I am puzzled, why it fails. Potentially there is an error somewhere else, but I didnt see it so far.

Comment: My mistake! I missunderstood the command, for iprob=1 it jumps. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

The form

```
go to ( 202 ), iprob
```

is a computed go to statement.  In such a statement there is a list of labels (here just the one `202`) and an integer expression (here `iprob`) which selects the label.

Label selection is by order in the list.  So, to select the first label the value of the expression should be `1`.  With `iprob` having the value `202` the 202nd label (if it exists) would be selected.  With the integer expression out of range (less than 1, more than the number of labels in the list) execution continues on to the next line.  Running through the goto, as you have it.

You may be thinking of assigned go to statements, where the label is determined by the value of an expression.  I won't go into details of that, though, as it is no longer part of the Fortran standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the issue.

Comment: The computed GOTO I always found somewhat confusing. I know this is fortran77, but the SELECTED CASE in fortran90 seems worth looking at in this case.